# Where is Qt Creator?

Tags: linux, qt, linux-mint

I've just downloaded Qt Creator with the online installer. But I can't find the program on my computer to run it! It's not in the mint menu, and I can't find one of those grey square things in the Qt folder to double-click on. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc - tags say mint linux, but also it doesn't really matter, as the folder structure of a qt install is pretty much identical across different operating systems

Answer (score 4):

It is in `/home/dev/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin` or wherever you installed Qt - tools - qtcreator - bin

Comment: Thank you for that!